# First half of 'if statement' in javascript is only firing once

Tags: javascript

I have and if/else statement that I am using to resize a background video, though I am encountering an error where the firs half of the statement  `if(video.style.height <= window.innerHeight && fired == false)` is only ever firing once on page resize...  The second half of the statement, the `else` part will then fire continuously, without error.  Is there any reason you guys can see?  I'm a bit of a JavaScript noob, so sorry if it is something obvious.

JS:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    var fullWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var fullHeight = window.innerHeight;

    var video = document.getElementById("test");
    var videoWidth = video.style.width;
    var videoHeight = video.style.height;

    console.log(videoHeight);
    console.log(fullHeight);

    var fired = false;

    if(video.style.height <= window.innerHeight && fired == false) {
        video.style.height = fullHeight + 'px';
        var fullWidthAdjusted = fullHeight * 1.7777777;
        video.style.width = fullWidthAdjusted + 'px';
        console.log(videoWidth);
        console.log("If statement working");
        fired = true;
    } else {
        video.style.width = fullWidth + 'px';
        var fullHeightAdjusted = fullWidth * .5625;
        video.style.height = fullHeightAdjusted + 'px';
        console.log("Wrong part of statement working");
        fired = true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it will fix your problem, but `element.style.height` is string in format `"1234px"` and `window.innerHeight` is number like `1234`.

edit:

instead of `video.style.height` try `parseInt(video.style.height, 10)`.

Answer (score 1):

The height style is a string, not a number. Before you have set the style, it will return an empty string, and that is less the string representation (implicitly converted) of the window inner height, so the first block is executed.

Once the style is set, it will return the height with the `px` appended, and that is not less than the string representation of the window inner height, so the second block is executed.

You can use the `parseInt` method to get the style as a number:

```
if(parseInt('0' + video.style.height, 10) <= window.innerHeight && fired == false) {
```

The `'0' +` before the string is to make the empty string that you get first turn into zero. Otherwise it would be `NaN` and the comparison would fail.

Comment: It seems to work both ways, with and without the '0'.  If it is better to use the '0' I will, but most thing I have read say 'less typing = better'.  Again, I'm new to this, so that might be wring in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Because the second condition in the if statement is `fired === false`,  which is not true after the first resize as you are setting `fired = true` inside both the `if` and `else` block.

If you want it to fire more than once remove  `&& fired === false`